# dragging and dropping whole folder using livewire

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-livewire

I have been using livewire to upload files, and it has been good. However, my user wanted to be able to just drag and drop their folder and let the system figure out the uploading. Here comes the problem.

When I drop multiple files, the system works just fine, but when i drop the folder, the system gave this error;
[It says permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edlot.png)

This is my code for uploading the file;

```
public function upload()
    {
        
        $this->validate([
            'pdfs.*' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:102400', // 1MB Max
        ]);
        
        foreach ($this->pdfs as $pdf) {
            $pdf->store('uploads');
            
        }
        
        session()->flash('message', 'PDF uploaded successfully!');
        
    }
```

This is my code for updating the file, if it is related to the matter at hand;

```
public function update(){

        //save doc

        // upload logic
        //dd('update details and upload');
        

        foreach ($this->pdfs as $pdf) {
            $pdf->store('uploads');
            //save into the document table and document attachment table
            $doc=new Document();
            $doc->patientRN=$this->patientRN;
            $doc->save();

            $docAttachment=new DocumentAttachment();
            $docAttachment->documents_id=$this->docId;
            $docAttachment->file_name=$pdf->getClientOriginalName();
            //$docAttachment->filename=$pdf->getClientOriginalName();
            $docAttachment->url=$pdf->store('uploads');
            $docAttachment->save();


        }
        
        $this->initData();
    }
```

I came from classic ASP and not very familiar with MVC or livewire for that matter, but it's okay i'm willing to learn

I was expecting to be able to upload the whole folder, and when i googled using terms such as 'laravel failed upload permission denied' i could not find anything related.